# BeagleBone Black MySQL

Tags: mysql, connection, embedded, workbench

I recently set up a MySQL server on my BeagleBone Black, it seems to work locally. Then I try to remote connect using MySQL Workbench on my laptop, but it said connection failed. Any idea why?

I also set up LightTPD, and that works fine. I am able to see a website from my laptop. So the connection there is good. I also check the iptables policy, and it is set to accept. I also ran netstat to see which port it's listening to, 3306. So I can't really think of why it don't work...

I am really new to this server, client, database things, so any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: it can issue on your laptop firewall so check on both end. and make sure you have opened port 3305 on both some time need to permission to Workbench also

Answer (score 0):

Try Node.js server instead of Lighttpd. Better it you connect your database from Node.js MVC app. Use express  or something like that.